# Haskell. How to print array for each sorted element in mergesort

Tags: sorting, haskell, recursion, functional-programming, mergesort

Im using Haskell to test my mergesort function but I don't know where to place the **trace** function so that it displays every time an element in the array is sorted.

An example is if I input [4,3,2,1] to be sorted, it should print the array for every iteration until it gets sorted:

```
[4,3,2,1]
[3,4,2,1]
[3,4,1,2]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Code:

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] ys         = ys
merge xs []         = xs
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | x < y     = x:merge xs (y:ys)
                    | otherwise = y:merge (x:xs) ys

halve :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
halve xs = (take lhx xs, drop lhx xs)
           where lhx = length xs `div` 2

msort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
msort []  = []
msort [x] = [x]
msort  xs = merge (msort left) (msort right)
            where (left,right) = halve xs
```

Comment: There is no "whole array" in each step, and there is no precise "time when an element is sorted" due to lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t easily trace the *entire* partially sorted list at each step, because you’re not constructing or recording that information anywhere—this code just constructs the final output list directly, and evaluating that list makes recursive calls to `msort` as needed to find the next element.

However, you could record each comparison during merging, which is enough information to verify the steps. For example, adding the following traces:

```
merge :: (Ord a, Show a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] ys         = ys
merge xs []         = xs
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x < y     = trace sorted  $ x:merge xs (y:ys)
  | otherwise = trace swapped $ y:merge (x:xs) ys
  where
    sorted = concat
      ["sorted:  ", show x, " < ", show y]
    swapped = concat
      ["swapped: ", show x, " >= ", show y]
```

(You’ll need to add a `Show` constraint in order to enable debug formatting of the element values.)

Evaluating this on an example input will show the decisions made for each comparison, in the order that the `(:)` constructors of the list are evaluated. I’ll also include a trace on each element to show when the comparison forces that element to be evaluated. Beside the program’s output, I’ve written the state of each sublist, which you can deduce from the trace:

```
> numbers = [1, 10, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7, 5, 6]
> labels = (("forced:  #" ++) . show <$> [0..])
> take 1 $ msort $ zipWith trace labels numbers
forced:  #0      -- [1]
forced:  #1      -- [10]
sorted:  1 < 10  -- [1, 10]
forced:  #3      -- [9]
forced:  #4      -- [3]
swapped: 9 >= 3  -- [3, 9]
forced:  #2      -- [2]
sorted:  2 < 3   -- [2, 3, 9]
sorted:  1 < 2   -- [1, 2, 3, 9, 10]
forced:  #5      -- [8]
forced:  #6      -- [4]
swapped: 8 >= 4  -- [4, 8]
forced:  #8      -- [5]
forced:  #9      -- [6]
sorted:  5 < 6   -- [5, 6]
forced:  #7      -- [7]
swapped: 7 >= 5  -- [5, 6, 7]
sorted:  4 < 5   -- [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
sorted:  1 < 4   -- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1]
```

Since we’re just taking the first element of the result, this is only performing as many comparisons as it takes to find the minimum. (A cleverly written lazy merge sort can do a little better at avoiding work than this.)

Note how the order in which the elements are evaluated shows the tree structure of the algorithm:

```
  #0
   │ #1
   └┬─┘    #3
    │       │ #4
    │   #2  └┬─┘
    │    └┬──┘   #5
    └┬────┘       │ #6
     │            └┬─┘    #8
     │             │       │ #9
     │             │   #7  └┬─┘
     │             │    └┬──┘
     │             └┬────┘
     └┬─────────────┘
```

So the end result is two sorted halves, `[1, 2, 3, 9, 10]` and `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, but the program doesn’t have to do any of the remaining merging, because we’ve determined that `1` is the minimum element, since the sublists are both sorted, and `1 < 4`.

So I’d say your function looks good! But you don’t have to take my word; you can also test it on random sample inputs with a property testing package like QuickCheck, for example, by verifying that it produces sorted results, or checking it against a known-correct `sort` implementation:

```
> :set -package QuickCheck
> import Test.QuickCheck

> isSorted xs = and $ zipWith (<=) xs (drop 1 xs)
> quickCheck $ \ xs -> isSorted (msort (xs :: [Int]))
…
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.

> quickCheck $ \ xs -> sort (xs :: [Int]) == msort xs
…
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and code! Finally got it to work.